# Visual Studio 2015 community edition, open folder missing

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use Visual Studio 15 community edition to work on Node projects.  From the article here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/12/open-any-folder-with-visual-studio-15-preview/ I should see an open folder option.  But in my edition VS 2015 Community Update 2, this option is missing.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 15 is not Visual Studio 2015.

Early in development, Microsoft usually refers to the next Visual Studio by its version number. In this case it's 15. When it becomes clearer when it will be released then it gets a proper name, Visual Studio 2017 in this case.

> Visual Studio 15 = Visual Studio 2017

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017)

What you're looking for is Visual Studio 2017. As of this answer only the RC (release candidate) version is available and can be downloaded from Microsoft's website.